# Android ADB Device gone as soon as Eclipse is started (Mac)

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

```
>adb devices
List of devices attached 
0123456789ABCDEF    device
```

As soon as I start eclipse the device doesn't show up anymore. To list it again I have to close Eclipse and do

```
>adb kill-server
>adb devices
```

So what is going on here? I can't use my Odys Next in eclipse if dab isn't listing it.

Comment: did u find a solution? please help? got NEO X7

Comment: Nope. Bought another device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will work using the AVDs and from time to time I will install it manually on the device.